Canvas fails to transfer ImageBitmap from Web Worker
In my HTML5/TypeScript game project I am trying to render chunks for a 2D world in a Web Worker into an OffscreenCanvas. As that rendering can take several seconds to complete (on lower-end devices like phones) it has to be done asynchroneously, otherwise the app would become unusable.
I separated the rendering from the Web-Worker code to make sure there is no bug elsewhere, and as long as I am not using the worker the output is fine. However if I use the worker I get a black image instead of what has been generated.
This is how it looks like without web-worker:

This is how it looks like with web-worker (exact same code otherwise):

Please note that in the latter case the image is not only black for some reason, but also the player (green square) is rendered behind the image, which is not what the code says. Inspection shows that the image generated by the web-worker exists and has the proper content, it however is not displayed properly. This makes me wonder if this is some origin issue?
Worker initialization code:
const renderChunkAsync: Function<ChunkRenderData, Supplier<Optional<ImageBitmap>>> = (renderData) => {
    const worker: Worker = new Worker(new URL('./chunkDrawerWorker.ts', import.meta.url))

    let drawingResult: Optional<ImageBitmap> = null
    worker.onmessage = (event: MessageEvent<ImageBitmap>) => {
        console.log('Worker done with ', event.data)
        drawingResult = event.data
        worker.terminate()
    }
    worker.postMessage(renderData)

//  const drawingResult = drawChunk(renderData)

    return () => drawingResult
}

Worker script:
const messageHandler: Consumer<MessageEvent<ChunkRenderData>> = ({ data }) => {
    const result = drawChunk(data)
    console.log('Woerker done with ', result)
    self.postMessage(result, { transfer: [result] })
}

self.onmessage = messageHandler

Actual rendering code:
export const drawChunk: Function<ChunkRenderData, ImageBitmap> = ({ tileData, imageSize, tileSize }) => {
    const tilesPerLine = Math.round(imageSize / tileSize)
    const canvas = new OffscreenCanvas(imageSize, imageSize)
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
    const color = 'blue'
    ctx.fillStyle = color
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, imageSize, imageSize)

    return canvas.transferToImageBitmap()
}

Rendering meta code:
    const renderer: Function<RenderOptions, Procedure> =
        ({ canvas, chunkController }) =>
        () => {
            const chunkSize = config.tileSizePx * CHUNK_DEF.SIZE
            const { width, height } = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
            canvas.width = width 
            canvas.height = height
            const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height)

            const tileSize: number = config.tileSizePx
            const offsetScreen = calculateScreenOffset(width, height, playerPos)

            const chunkPlayer = chunkController.getChunkForPos(playerPos)
            const chunkPosScreen = offsetScreen(chunkPlayer.worldPosition)
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'red'
            ctx.strokeRect(chunkPosScreen.x, chunkPosScreen.y, chunkSize, chunkSize)
            const chunkImg = chunkPlayer.getCanvas()
            chunkImg && ctx.drawImage(chunkImg, chunkPosScreen.x, chunkPosScreen.y, chunkSize, chunkSize)

            const ps = offsetScreen(playerPos)
            ctx.fillStyle = 'green'
            ctx.fillRect(ps.x, ps.y, tileSize, tileSize)
        }


There is nothing in renderChunkAsync that let's know outside script when drawingResult is available. How do you know it is? Why not make it return a Promise? Also, avoid single use Workers, they are not cheap at all to generate, and when dealing with OffscreenCanvas you could miss the rendering step which happens after rAF (though here with transferToImageBitmap() it is supposed to work).

This is currently a test script with of course lots of work to do. The benefit of not yet having the promise is that I can clearly see the pre- and post state of the system, as everything is only updated on keystroke. Workers will also be created rarely in the final system as everything is cached.

Ok... but so.. you're actually not sure it was available when you tried to draw it, right? What if you actually make sure of it?

I am sure that it is available, because I am constantly printing the content of that imageBitmap onto the console. It definitely has content.
Somehow, however, the result is just black overlaying everything. This leads me to believe that it is something else.
